# Writing a kernel mode profiler for processes in python

Tags: python, kernel

I would like seek some guidance in writing a "process profiler" which runs in kernel mode. I am asking for a kernel mode profiler is because I run loads of applications and I do not want my profiler to be swapped out.

When I said "process profiler" I mean to something that would monitor resource usage by the process. including usage of threads and their statistics.

And I wish to write this in python. Point me to some modules or helpful resource.

Please provide me guidance/suggestion for doing it.

### Thanks,

Edit::: Would like to add that currently my interest isto write only for linux. however after i built it i will have to support windows.

Comment: I don't understand your edit, you have to support linux and then windows ? I guess lots of the profiling code would be system-dependent...
have you looked at any existing tool to be sure they're not ok ? Valgrind, oprofile, exmap...this kind of thing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's going to be very difficult to do the process monitoring part in Python, since the python interpreter doesn't run in the kernel.

I suspect there are two easy approaches to this:

1. use the /proc filesystem if you have one (you don't mention your OS)
2. Use dtrace if you have dtrace (again, without the OS, who knows.)

---

Okay, following up after the edit.

First, there's no way you're going to be able to write code that runs in the kernel, in python, and is portable between Linux and Windows.  Or at least if you were to, it would be a hack that would live in glory forever.

That said, though, if your purpose is to process Python, there are a lot of Python tools available to get information from the Python interpreter at run time.

If instead your desire is to get process information from *other* processes in general, you're going to need to examine the options available to you in the various OS APIs.  Linux has a /proc filesystem; that's a useful start.  I suspect Windows has similar APIs, but I don't know them.

If you have to write kernel code, you'll almost certainly need to write it in C or C++.

Comment: I agree for the /proc, I've used the smaps files that you can find for each pid...you could parse this file using python but it's not going to run in kernel space... 

Note that these files are volatile so always updated (you could look at the exmap tool if you want...)....

Comment: +1 Charlie. Python and Kernel-mode sounds like a nightmare ;)

Comment: Another option might be to write a small module that writes data to /proc, then process that with python.

Comment: @Doug - might be better to parse dtrace-for-linux output than maintain a kernel module :S it's quite parsable.

Comment: @Aiden - True, but I'm assuming the whole point of this project is to do something that isn't already done by tools like DTrace. If that's not the point, then surely one should use DTrace :-)

Comment: @Doug - aye ;) I'm still grimacing over the thought of python running in the kernel.

Comment: I was actually kind of guessing, based on the phrasing etc, that the questioner was relatively new to this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

**don't** try and get python running in kernel space!

You would be much better using an existing tool and getting it to spit out XML that can be sucked into Python. I wouldn't want to port the Python interpreter to kernel-mode (it sounds grim writing it).

The /proc option does sound good.

**some code**  code that reads proc information to determine memory usage and such. Should get you going:

http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py **reads memory information of processes using Python through /proc/smaps** like charlie suggested.

Comment: What language should i be chosing to get something running in kernel space ...??

Comment: The C programming language. Although, no offence, but if you have to ask then playing with the kernel will be overwhelming. Have a look at the python script in my post ... should give you ideas :) It reads the memory information of processes using Python.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at `PSI`? (http://www.psychofx.com/psi/)

"PSI is a Python module providing direct access to real-time system and process information. PSI is a Python C extension, providing the most efficient access to system information directly from system calls."

it might give you what you are looking for.   .... or at least a starting point.

---

Edit 2014:

I'd recommend checking out `psutil` instead:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil

`psutil` is actively maintained and has some nifty process monitoring features.  `PSI` seems to be somewhat dead (last release 2009).

Comment: PSI has moved here: https://bitbucket.org/chrismiles/psi/wiki/Home but it seems to have deceased.

Comment: last release of PSI to PyPI was 2009.  psutil has similar goals, but is actively maintained: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil

Answer (score 0):

Some of your comments on other answers suggest that you are a relatively inexperienced programmer. Therefore I would strongly suggest that you stay away from kernel programming, as it is very hard even for experienced programmers.

Why would you want to write something that

- is a very complex system (just look at existing profiling infrastructures and how complex they are)
- can not be done in python (I don't know any kernel that would allow execution of python in kernel mode)
- already exists ([oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/) on Linux)

Comment: That is kinda irrelevant for the questions. Im guessing one would want to write it for learning purposes. It doesnt matter if it already exists or if it is difficult...

Comment: Writing a kernel mode profiler is not something one would do just "for learning purposes". A fake user space profiler would probably provide just as much learning experience without the hardships of programming a kernel module.